# add record to pandas dataframe by copying part of existing record

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to process bug status data from bugzilla database. Here's my df.head()

```
   bug_id         creation_ts     added            bug_when
0  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  ASSIGNED 2006-07-29 09:34:04
1  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  NEEDINFO 2007-05-30 17:28:46
2  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  ASSIGNED 2007-05-31 09:20:40
3  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  CLOSED   2012-03-28 10:54:12
4  200247 2006-07-26 10:40:03  CLOSED   2006-08-14 12:05:47
```

This lists bug status activities for bugs **194402** and **200247**. Bugzilla doesn't have activity record for when bug is created. I was wondering if there's an easy pandas way of adding a record by copying information from another row? I want to use **creation_ts** as **bug_when** with **added** value of **NEW**. That would result in following:

```
   bug_id         creation_ts     added            bug_when
0  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  NEW      2006-06-07 15:40:13
1  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  ASSIGNED 2006-07-29 09:34:04
2  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  NEEDINFO 2007-05-30 17:28:46
3  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  ASSIGNED 2007-05-31 09:20:40
4  194402 2006-06-07 15:40:13  CLOSED   2012-03-28 10:54:12
5  200247 2006-07-26 10:40:03  NEW      2006-07-26 10:40:03
6  200247 2006-07-26 10:40:03  CLOSED   2006-08-14 12:05:47
```

Or do I need to break this up with creating sub dataframes for each bug and then adding a record there?

I have tried following

```
df = DataFrame(data=list(activities), columns=activities.keys())
# setup empty dataframe to store processed rows
xf = DataFrame(columns=['bug_id', 'added', 'bug_when'])
# set bug_id and creation_ts as index
df = df.set_index(['bug_id','creation_ts'])
# loop through indexes
with Timer() as t:
    for index in set(df.index):
        bug_id, creation_ts = index
        # setup new row
        new_row = dict(bug_id=bug_id, bug_when=creation_ts, added='NEW')
        # convert row to dataframe and append
        xf = xf.append( DataFrame([new_row]), ignore_index=True)
        # get bug activties from dataframe by index
        bug_activities = df.ix[index]
        # add 'bug_id' row as index is ignored
        bug_activities['bug_id'] = bug_id
        # append bug_activities
        xf = xf.append( bug_activities, ignore_index=True)
logging.info("pandas done in %s" % t.interval)
```

But running this on 100, 1000 and 1000 records takes 0.75, 8.29 and 146.58 sec which is not good.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd groupby the 'bug_id' column, then take the first entry and append this back to your dataframe:

```
In [67]:
# groupby bug_id, take first of each group and reset the index
first = df.groupby('bug_id').first().reset_index()
# now assign the timestamp and set the added column to 'NEW'
first['bug_when'], first['added'] = first['creation_ts'], 'NEW'
first

Out[67]:
   bug_id          creation_ts added             bug_when
0  194402  2006-06-07 15:40:13   NEW  2006-06-07 15:40:13
1  200247   2006-07-26 10:40:0   NEW   2006-07-26 10:40:0

In [68]:
# append back to dataframe and ignore the index so it is unique
df.append(first, ignore_index=True)

Out[68]:
   bug_id          creation_ts     added             bug_when
0  194402  2006-06-07 15:40:13  ASSIGNED  2006-07-29 09:34:04
1  194402  2006-06-07 15:40:13  NEEDINFO  2007-05-30 17:28:46
2  194402  2006-06-07 15:40:13  ASSIGNED  2007-05-31 09:20:40
3  194402  2006-06-07 15:40:13    CLOSED  2012-03-28 10:54:12
4  200247   2006-07-26 10:40:0    CLOSED  2006-08-14 12:05:47
5  194402  2006-06-07 15:40:13       NEW  2006-06-07 15:40:13
6  200247   2006-07-26 10:40:0       NEW   2006-07-26 10:40:0
```

Comment: 10000 bugs with 27309 status change activities are processed in 0.04s